# Display objects at the same time using Swift and Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am making a seating chart for a cafe using Swift and Parse. Currently I am able to save the x,y coordinates for each table in Parse and have the data points be loaded in the app.

It works perfectly well, but when the tables do load, they do not load together in unison but by individual tables (depending on internet speed). I was wondering if there was a way to delay the display until all the coordinates are fully loaded, so that the seating chart is loaded in unison.

Comment: Is parse calling back multiple times until it's finally given you all the data? There must be a way to write a query that gets all the data and only calls back once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `completion` so that all data is loaded, before you show your tables. Like that:

```
//Find the objects
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    //Done loading all objects
    if error == nil {

        // Do something with the found objects

        //Load your tables

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)")
    }

}
```

That way, the gui waits for the query to finish and after that, all your tables will be loaded at the same time.